# Converting the Pyspark RDD into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a Pyspark RDD as shown in the output below, how can I convert it to pandas dataframe.

```
rdd.take(3)

['REVISION 6 233188 AmericanSamoa 2001-01-19T01:12:51Z ip:office.bomis.com ip:office.bomis.com\nCATEGORY\nIMAGE\nMAIN\nTALK\nUSER\nUSER_TALK\nOTHER\nEXTERNAL\nTEMPLATE\nCOMMENT *\nMINOR 0\nTEXTDATA 1516',
 'REVISION 6 133180191 AmericanSamoa 2007-05-24T14:41:33Z Ngaiklin 4477979\nCATEGORY\nIMAGE\nMAIN\nTALK\nUSER\nUSER_TALK\nOTHER\nEXTERNAL\nTEMPLATE R_from_CamelCase\nCOMMENT Robot: Automated text replacement (-\\[\\[(.*?[\\:|\\|])*?(.+?)\\]\\] +\\g<2>)\nMINOR 1\nTEXTDATA 5',
 'REVISION 8 233189 AppliedEthics 2001-01-20T15:01:12Z ip:pD950754B.dip.t-dialin.net ip:pD950754B.dip.t-dialin.net\nCATEGORY\nIMAGE\nMAIN\nTALK\nUSER\nUSER_TALK\nOTHER\nEXTERNAL\nTEMPLATE\nCOMMENT *\nMINOR 1\nTEXTDATA 9']
```

I used the following snippet, but the output is coming under a single column.

```
df = rdd.map(lambda x: str(x)).map(lambda w: w.split('    ')).toDF()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+
|                  _1|
+--------------------+
|REVISION 6 233188...|
|REVISION 6 133180...|
```

Answer (score 0):

For converting it to Pandas DataFrame, use `toPandas()`.

`toDF()` will convert the RDD to PySpark DataFrame (which you need in order to convert to pandas eventually).

```py
# Splitting by `\n`
an_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: str(x)).map(lambda w: w.split('\n'))

# Creating columns recursively using dictionary
spark_df = an_rdd.map(lambda x: {'column_{}'.format(idx) : val 
                        for (idx, val) in enumerate(x)}).map(lambda x: Row(**x)).toDF()

# Converting to pandas
pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
```

Comment: Please reread my question, the problem is in rdd.map(lambda x: str(x)).map(lambda w: w.split('    '))

Comment: oh, sorry, I missed that part. Your `split` code does not seem to be splitting at all with four spaces. The data snippet you have given, it doesn't have four spaces anywhere. Can you identify by which character you want to split the strings?

Comment: Updated the answer with `\n` as separator.